# Autofac with SignalR in Nop Commerce Plugin

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, autofac, nopcommerce

I'm building a Nop Commerce plugin that uses a SignalR hub to update the client of the status of a long running process. The version of Nop Commerce is v3.50. I've installed the SignalR Nuget Package. I then installed NuGet Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 2.1.0 in Nop.Web project so that my OWIN startup class would run inside my plugin. Now I need to use Autofac dependency injection in my SignalR hub. I installed the NuGet package Autofac ASP.NET SignalR Integration 3.0.2 into my plugin and set things up according to the instructions here:

http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/signalr.html

I go to build my project and I get the error:

Assembly 'Nop.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Autofac, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Autofac, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da'   c:\dev\Nop350Source\Libraries\Nop.Core\bin\Debug\Nop.Core.dll

So Nop.Core is using a newer version of Autofac than the one Autofac ASP.NET SignalR Integration 3.0.2 relies on. Is there a way to make this work?

As an alternative, what other strategy could I use for a long running process other than SignalR? My plugin will be importing about 50,000 products into the store while downloading each products images from a server and then parsing and adding categories, tags, and manufacturers. I think the process will probably take a day or so to complete if I'm optimistic that each product could be imported in 2 seconds. I think realistically it will take longer because downloading 3 images per product will be the bottleneck in the project.

Comment: what version is the autofac pkg itself?

Comment: In my project it is Autofac 3.1.3. In Nop Commerce it is 3.5.2

Comment: so upgrade your project's autofac to 3.5.2.

Comment: I did that and now get the error:  Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: The problem is that Calling assembly : Autofac.Integration.SignalR, Version=3.0.0.0 wants an older version of autofac to work and I need Autofac.Integration.SignalR to make dependency injection work with the project

Comment: To fix your next error, I believe you remove the autofac dll from references and then re-add it from the file system to fix the reference.  Also it's not looking for an older version, it's telling you that there is a version mismatch on what it's expecting and what you're giving it per 1st error.

Comment: I removed my Autofac reference, then browsed to the packages directory and found the Autofac 3.5.2 folder and used the dll in side there. I am still getting the same error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: If you didn't resolve this, you need to add a biinding redirect to your config file.

<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.2.0" newVersion="2.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>